# Read a .php file using php

Tags: php, file, file-upload

How to read a .php file using php

Comment: You can just `include` the file, no?

Comment: Why you can not read a .php file? what problem you face?

Comment: I just get a blank page while reading a *.php file using fgets

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry I dont want to include a file. I just read a file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's say you have two files `a.php` and `b.php` on same folder.

Code on the file `b.php`

```
<?php

echo "hi";

?>
```

and code on `a.php`

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('b.php');
echo $data;
```

You access `a.php` on browser.

What do you see? A blank page.

Please check the page source now. It is there.

But not showing in browser as `<?php` is not a valid html tag. So browser can not render it properly to show as output.

```
<?php
$data = htmlentities(file_get_contents('b.php'));
echo $data;
```

Now you can see the output in browser.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the content generated by PHP, then

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://host/path/file.php');
```

If you want to get the source code of the PHP file, then

```
$data = file_get_contents('path/file.php');
```

Remember that `file_get_contents()` will not work if your server has `*allow_url_fopen*` turned off.

Comment: I need to get the content generated by PHP as in your first example but without using web server and HTTP requests. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Of course, if you have the file locally you can directly open and see the content. FYI, PHP is running on a web server. You are trying to so something which isn't possible

Comment: I want to (write tests, which) verify that the content I get over HTTP request is exactly what I expect it to be. Obviously with dynamic parts being processed. I can't compare the source file to the HTTP response body. I need to compare the processed output without using HTTP with the same sent over HTTP. You may also ask why would I want to do this. A short answer: because I need ;-) A longer one: In order to make sure that problems with a third party middleware outside my domain do not happen again unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

```
//get the real path of the file in folder if necessary
$path = realpath("/path/to/myfilename.php");

//read the file
$lines = file($path,FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Each line of the 'myfilename.php' will be stored as a string in the array '$lines'.
And then, you may use all string functions in php. More info about available string functions is available here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php