# Ace editor read php file gets commented

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I use ACE to edit css/html and php files, html/css works great.
However, when i try to open a php file with ACE for editing, the editor does not show any content. But when looking at the page source, the content is somehow turned into HTML comment. Does someone know to fix this?

Code:

```
<div id="editor"><?php readfile($_GET['file']); ?></div>
```

'file' is a php file and the contents are not visible in ace editor but are turned into HTML comment, visible in page source.

Comment: So, the `ace` fact not relevant.. So the problem is (I guess) in the server. Have you tried to use `file_get_contents` instead of `readfile`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965362/read-a-php-file-using-php

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the mark that does not allow showing the PHP code in a PHP page. I solved the issue withhtmlspecialchars`that translates`into<?ph`p, so the printing code will not be processed by the PHP engine and will be visible.

```
<div id="editor"><?php echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($_GET['file']));?></div>
```

Before writing the PHP CODE back to a file you must first revert that action using `htmlspecialchars_decode`, then the `&lt;?php` will be translated back to `<?php`, keeping your code safe into the file.

```
<?php
$sourceCodeUpdated = (array_key_exists('editor',$_POST)) ? $_POST['editor'] : '';
file_put_contents('file.php',htmlspecialchars_decode($sourceCodeUpdated));
?>
```

Comment: I used `html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars($code))` to load compatible with html and also show decoded code